# Boot OS from partition

Tags: linux, boot, bios, multi-boot

I have a partition on which I already burned a Linux distribution. However when I reboot my computer and go in to the BIOS to select the partition I can't seem to find it.

I suspect I need to do something else then just making a new partition on my HDD and burning my ISO onto it. What am I missing?

Comment: You don't *"burn"* a HDD; you're misusing jargon.  An ISO image is intended for an optical disc (CD or DVD), and should not be written to a HDD partition.

Comment: @sawdust Probably I messed up the terms. I used PowerISO to extract the ISO to a partition of the HDD, how can I boot from it?

Comment: *"how can I boot from it"* -- Apparently not possible.  Follow the instructions for using the ISO.  Write it to an optical disc as it was intended to be used, or if it's a hybrid image, to a USB Flash drive.

Comment: @sawdust So there is no possibility of dual booting without a USB/Optical Disk?

Comment: "Dual booting" is a separate issue from misusing an ISO image.  The ISO image, properly booted, will allow you to ***install*** the Linux distro in a HDD partition, and allow dual (or triple) boot from the HDD if other OSes are detected in other primary partitions.

Comment: @sawdust Heh well that makes a bit more sense now! It is my first time doing something like this so thank you for your time.